# How to search query by field with exact match in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm trying to search for a document, by field value. The field is of type String that was defined in the index like this:

```
"field" : { 
        "type" : "string"
 }
```

There are no other settings to the index but the mappings.

I tried various queries to try to find documents with `field="test"`, and every time I get no results or results that contain that substring `"test"`. I want the document where `"field"` matches `"test"` exactly.

I tried `match`, `match_phrase`, `term` and `query_string`, none of which seems to work as I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `term` query with keyword like this

```
{
   "query" : {
      "term" : {
         "field.keyword" : "test"
      }
   }
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: I doubt this is the correct answer to the original question, as the mapping in the question is using the `string` type. A type available in earlier versions of Elasticsearch, whereas the answer is relying on a mapping to type `keyword`, a newer type introduced to support exact-match search, sorting and analytics.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are on an Elasticsearch version prior to version 6, which still supported the `String` type. More recent version of Elasticsearch replaced the `string` field-type with types `keyword` and `text` to make it easier to support the two use-cases of `exact-match` and `full-text` search use cases.

You need to change your mapping to support exact-match search as follows:

```
{
  "field": {
    "type" "string",
    "index": "not_analyzed"
  }
}
```

As you cannot change an existing mapping, you need to do that change on a new index and get everything re-indexed.

If you are on Elasticsearch version 6+ simply use a field of type `keyword` for exact-match searches. By default string fields get mapped to a multi-field made of of 2 fields:

- one of type `text` (for full-text search), referenced by
- one of type `keyword` (for exact match search), referenced by .keyword

Hereby an interesting blog post about that topic: [Strings are dead, long live strings!](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings)